# How to implement equals and hashcode for enum classes

Tags: java, enums, hashmap

I have an interface name Types

```
public interface Types
{       
    public String getName();    
}
```

Two enum classes are extending this interface like

```
public enum AlphaTypes implements Types
{
    Alpha("alpha"),Common("common")
    private String name;

    private AlphaTypes(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }   
}

public enum BetaTypes implements Types
{
    Beta("beta"),Common("common")
    private String name;

    private BetaTypes(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }   
}
```

The requirement is have a map which takes Types as key
like `Map<Types,Object> map;`

How to implement equals and hashcode, such that the map keys are unique even for common enum values?

Comment: why not have Map<Types,List<T>> of some sort?

Comment: Have you tried just using it with the default implementations? Reference equality should be fine since these are `enum`s (so you won't have different instances with the same values), and I see no reason why the default `hashCode` wouldn't suffice.

Comment: Remember enum members are singletons, so == is adequate as a test for equality . all enum classes implicitly extend java.lang.Enum which has final implementations of both. equals uses == and hashCode uses Object.hashCode. Try overriding them in any enum and you'll get a compiler error Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2964704/why-java-does-not-allow-overriding-equalsobject-in-an-enum

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The class `java.lang.Enum` declare both `equals()` and `hashCode()` as `final`, thus you'll get compiler errors trying to override them.

That being said, your example above works as you desire - if you add `AlphaTypes.Common` and `BetaTypes.Common` to a `Map` you'll get a map with two elements:

```
public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception
{
    Map<Types,Object> map = new HashMap<Types,Object>();

    map.put( AlphaTypes.Common , "b" );
    map.put( BetaTypes.Common , "b" );

    System.out.println( "size=" + map.size());
}
```

> size=2

Cheers,